# Combine two arrays of objects according to different periods of time in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I have two arrays of objects `periods` and `people`. `periods` refers to the different periods of time that an organization went through. `people` refers to the people that were part of that organization. In the result, I want to attach each individual person to the period when they were part of the organization. To do that I am planing to do two different transformations. A sample of the data follows:

**DATA**

```
periods = [
  { start_date: "2017-01-01", end_date: "2017-12-01", period: 1 },
  { start_date: "2018-01-01", end_date: "2018-12-01", period: 2 },
  { start_date: "2019-01-01", end_date: "2019-12-01", period: 3 }
]
```

```
people = [
  { name: "Paul", 
    start_date_org: "2017-01-01", 
    end_date_org: "2018-04-01" },
  { name: "Terence",
    start_date_org: "2018-06-01",
    end_date_org: "2019-12-01" },
  { name: "Kylian",
    start_date_org: "2017-06-01", 
    end_date_org: "2019-12-01" }
]
```

How can I combine/merge these two files to get the following transformations?

**1st transformation**: Attach each individual person to the `period/s` when they were part of the organization. If possible, add `years` only as a reference.

```
result1 = [
  {
    name: "Paul",
    start_date_org: "2017-01-01",
    end_date_org: "2018-06-01",
    periods: [1, 2],
    year: [2017, 2018]
  },
  {
    name: "Terence",
    start_date_org: "2018-06-01",
    end_date_org: "2019-12-01",
    periods: [2, 3],
    year: [2018, 2019]
  },
  {
    name: "Kylian",
    start_date_org: "2017-06-01",
    end_date_org: "2019-12-01",
    periods: [1, 2, 3],
    year: [2017, 2018, 2019]
  }
]
```

**2nd transformation**: Expand the result. One object per person and period.

```
result2 = [
  {
    name: "Paul",
    start_date_org: "2017-01-01",
    end_date_org: "2018-06-01",
    period: 1,
    year: 2017
  },
  {
    name: "Paul",
    start_date_org: "2017-01-01",
    end_date_org: "2018-06-01",
    period: 2,
    year: 2018
  },
  {
    name: "Terence",
    start_date_org: "2018-06-01",
    end_date_org: "2019-12-01",
    period: 2,
    year: 2018
  },
  {
    name: "Terence",
    start_date_org: "2018-06-01",
    end_date_org: "2019-12-01",
    period: 3,
    year: 2019
  },
  {
    name: "Kylian",
    start_date_org: "2017-06-01",
    end_date_org: "2019-12-01",
    period: 1,
    year: 2017
  },
  {
    name: "Kylian",
    start_date_org: "2017-06-01",
    end_date_org: "2019-12-01",
    period: 2,
    year: 2018
  },
  {
    name: "Kylian",
    start_date_org: "2017-06-01",
    end_date_org: "2019-12-01",
    period: 3,
    year: 2019
  }
]
```

My best attempt so far using an if statement for the first transformation follows:

```
parseTime = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d")

people.map((d, i) => {
  periods.map((x, i) => {
    if (
      parseTime(x.start_date_org) >= parseTime(d.start_date) &&
      parseTime(x.start_date_org) <= parseTime(d.end_date)
    ) {
      d.period = x.period;
    }
  });
  return d;
})
```

Any advice is welcome!

Comment: Should this work for arbitrary periods, off of year boundaries? Are the periods of time and of a person's work inclusive of the last date?

Answer (score 1):

Here is not the most beautiful but working solution:

```
var periods = [
    { start_date: "2017-01-01", end_date: "2017-12-01", period: 1 },
    { start_date: "2018-01-01", end_date: "2018-12-01", period: 2 },
    { start_date: "2019-01-01", end_date: "2019-12-01", period: 3 }
];

var people = [
    { name: "Paul",
        start_date_org: "2017-01-01",
        end_date_org: "2018-04-01" },
    { name: "Terence",
        start_date_org: "2018-06-01",
        end_date_org: "2019-12-01" },
    { name: "Kylian",
        start_date_org: "2017-06-01",
        end_date_org: "2019-12-01" }
];

periods.map(p => {
    p.start_date = new Date(p.start_date);
    p.end_date = new Date(p.end_date);
});

people.map(p => {
    p.start_date_org = new Date(p.start_date_org);
    p.end_date_org = new Date(p.end_date_org);
});

var first_transformation = people;

first_transformation.map(p => {
    var chosen_periods = periods.filter(per => {
        return (p.start_date_org >= per.start_date && p.start_date_org <= per.end_date) ||
            (p.end_date_org >= per.start_date && p.end_date_org <= per.end_date) ||
            (p.start_date_org < per.start_date && p.end_date_org > per.end_date)
    });
    p.periods = chosen_periods.map(per => per.period);
    p.years = chosen_periods.map(per => per.start_date.getFullYear());
});
first_transformation.map(p => {
    p.start_date_org = p.start_date_org.toISOString().substring(0,10);
    p.end_date_org = p.end_date_org.toISOString().substring(0,10);
})

var second_transformation = [];

first_transformation.forEach(p => {
    p.years.forEach((year, i) => {
        second_transformation.push({
            name: p.name,
            start_date_org: p.start_date_org,
            end_date_org: p.end_date_org,
            period: p.periods[i],
            year: year
        })
    })
})
```

At the end you will have in `first_transformation` and `second_transformation` the data you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the one I made for the first example.

```js
periods = [{
    start_date: "2017-01-01",
    end_date: "2017-12-01",
    period: 1
  },
  {
    start_date: "2018-01-01",
    end_date: "2018-12-01",
    period: 2
  },
  {
    start_date: "2019-01-01",
    end_date: "2019-12-01",
    period: 3
  }
]

people = [{
    name: "Paul",
    start_date_org: "2017-01-01",
    end_date_org: "2018-04-01"
  },
  {
    name: "Terence",
    start_date_org: "2018-06-01",
    end_date_org: "2019-12-01"
  },
  {
    name: "Kylian",
    start_date_org: "2017-06-01",
    end_date_org: "2019-12-01"
  }
]

wanted_result = [{
    name: "Paul",
    start_date_org: "2017-01-01",
    end_date_org: "2018-06-01",
    periods: [1, 2],
    year: [2017, 2018]
  },
  {
    name: "Terence",
    start_date_org: "2018-06-01",
    end_date_org: "2019-12-01",
    periods: [2, 3],
    year: [2018, 2019]
  },
  {
    name: "Kylian",
    start_date_org: "2017-06-01",
    end_date_org: "2019-12-01",
    periods: [1, 2, 3],
    year: [2017, 2018, 2019]
  }
]

function usingNames(people, periods) {
  return people.map(person => {
    const personsPeriods = [];

    for (period of periods) {
      if (new Date(period.start_date) <= new Date(person.end_date_org) && new Date(person.start_date_org) <= new Date(period.end_date)) personsPeriods.push(period)
    }

    return {
      ...person,
      periods: [...personsPeriods.map(p => p.period)],
      year: [...personsPeriods.map(p => new Date(p.start_date).getFullYear())],
    }
  })
}

console.log(usingNames(people, periods))
```

Here's the example for the second example.

```js
periods = [{
    start_date: "2017-01-01",
    end_date: "2017-12-01",
    period: 1
  },
  {
    start_date: "2018-01-01",
    end_date: "2018-12-01",
    period: 2
  },
  {
    start_date: "2019-01-01",
    end_date: "2019-12-01",
    period: 3
  }
]

people = [{
    name: "Paul",
    start_date_org: "2017-01-01",
    end_date_org: "2018-04-01"
  },
  {
    name: "Terence",
    start_date_org: "2018-06-01",
    end_date_org: "2019-12-01"
  },
  {
    name: "Kylian",
    start_date_org: "2017-06-01",
    end_date_org: "2019-12-01"
  }
]

wanted_result = [
  {
    name: "Paul",
    start_date_org: "2017-01-01",
    end_date_org: "2018-06-01",
    period: 1,
    year: 2017
  },
  {
    name: "Paul",
    start_date_org: "2017-01-01",
    end_date_org: "2018-06-01",
    period: 2,
    year: 2018
  },
  {
    name: "Terence",
    start_date_org: "2018-06-01",
    end_date_org: "2019-12-01",
    period: 2,
    year: 2018
  },
  {
    name: "Terence",
    start_date_org: "2018-06-01",
    end_date_org: "2019-12-01",
    period: 3,
    year: 2019
  },
  {
    name: "Kylian",
    start_date_org: "2017-06-01",
    end_date_org: "2019-12-01",
    period: 1,
    year: 2017
  },
  {
    name: "Kylian",
    start_date_org: "2017-06-01",
    end_date_org: "2019-12-01",
    period: 2,
    year: 2018
  },
  {
    name: "Kylian",
    start_date_org: "2017-06-01",
    end_date_org: "2019-12-01",
    period: 3,
    year: 2019
  }
]

function usingNames(people, periods) {
  return people.flatMap(person => {
    const personsPeriods = [];

    for (period of periods) {
      if (new Date(period.start_date) <= new Date(person.end_date_org) && new Date(person.start_date_org) <= new Date(period.end_date)) personsPeriods.push(period)
    }
    
    return personsPeriods.flatMap(p => {
      return {
        ...person,
        period: p.period,
        year: new Date(p.start_date).getFullYear(),
      }
    })
  })
}

console.log(usingNames(people, periods))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example that first maps over the periods and creates relevant properties for later comparison.

**Preparation**

```
// map over periods and create dates and isolate 'year'
const periods_ = periods.map((p) => ({
  ...p,
  period_start_date: parseTime(p.start_date),
  period_end_date: parseTime(p.end_date),
  year: parseTime(p.start_date).getFullYear(),
}));
```

**Transform 1**

Is mostly taken up determining which periods intersect the persons tenure within a [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) call, then returning these periods mapped to `period` and `year` props

```
const transform1 = people.map((p) => {

  const person_periods = periods_.filter((p_) =>
    p_.period_start_date <= parseTime(p.end_date_org)
    && parseTime(p.start_date_org) <= p_.period_end_date
  );

  return {
    ...p,
    periods: person_periods.map(({ period }) => period),
    years: person_periods.map(({ year }) => year),
  };
});
```

**Transform 2**

Based on transform 1 this is a one line [`flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) flattening the previously mapped `periods` and `years`.

```
const transform2 = transform1.flatMap(({ periods, years, ...p }) =>
  years.map((year, i) => ({ ...p, period: periods[i], year }))
);
```

```js
const periods = [ { start_date: '2017-01-01', end_date: '2017-12-01', period: 1 }, { start_date: '2018-01-01', end_date: '2018-12-01', period: 2 }, { start_date: '2019-01-01', end_date: '2019-12-01', period: 3 }, ];
const people = [ { name: 'Paul', start_date_org: '2017-01-01', end_date_org: '2018-04-01', }, { name: 'Terence', start_date_org: '2018-06-01', end_date_org: '2019-12-01', }, { name: 'Kylian', start_date_org: '2017-06-01', end_date_org: '2019-12-01', }, ];

const parseTime = d3.timeParse('%Y-%m-%d');

// map over periods and create dates and isolate 'year'
const periods_ = periods.map((p) => ({
  ...p,
  period_start_date: parseTime(p.start_date),
  period_end_date: parseTime(p.end_date),
  year: parseTime(p.start_date).getFullYear(),
}));

// transform1
const transform1 = people.map((p) => {

  const person_periods = periods_.filter((p_) =>
    p_.period_start_date <= parseTime(p.end_date_org)
    && parseTime(p.start_date_org) <= p_.period_end_date
  );

  return {
    ...p,
    periods: person_periods.map(({ period }) => period),
    years: person_periods.map(({ year }) => year),
  };
});

// transform 2
const transform2 = transform1.flatMap(({ periods, years, ...p }) =>
  years.map((year, i) => ({ ...p, period: periods[ i ], year }))
);

console.log(transform1);
console.log(transform2);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.0.1/d3.min.js"></script>
```

---

#### Using Array#reduce()

Alternatively, you can combine the two into a single [`Array#reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) call, still preparing the `periods` array by mapping over it and parsing the dates and adding a `year` property for convenience later, and then reducing into a tuple accumulating `transform1` and `transform2`.

```
const [ transform1, transform2 ] = people.reduce(([t1, t2], p) => {

  const person_periods = periods_.filter((p_) =>
    p_.period_start_date <= parseTime(p.end_date_org)
    && parseTime(p.start_date_org) <= p_.period_end_date
  );

  t1.push({
    ...p,
    periods: person_periods.map(({ period }) => period),
    years: person_periods.map(({ year }) => year),
  });

  t2.push(...person_periods.map(({ period, year }, i) => ({ ...p, period, year })));

  return [t1, t2];
}, [[], []]);
```

```js
const periods = [ { start_date: '2017-01-01', end_date: '2017-12-01', period: 1 }, { start_date: '2018-01-01', end_date: '2018-12-01', period: 2 }, { start_date: '2019-01-01', end_date: '2019-12-01', period: 3 }, ];
const people = [ { name: 'Paul', start_date_org: '2017-01-01', end_date_org: '2018-04-01', }, { name: 'Terence', start_date_org: '2018-06-01', end_date_org: '2019-12-01', }, { name: 'Kylian', start_date_org: '2017-06-01', end_date_org: '2019-12-01', }, ];

const parseTime = d3.timeParse('%Y-%m-%d');

// map over periods and create dates and isolate 'year'
const periods_ = periods.map((p) => ({
  ...p,
  period_start_date: parseTime(p.start_date),
  period_end_date: parseTime(p.end_date),
  year: parseTime(p.start_date).getFullYear(),
}));

// reduce into tuple [t1, t2] and destructure
const [ transform1, transform2 ] = people.reduce(([t1, t2], p) => {

  const person_periods = periods_.filter((p_) =>
    p_.period_start_date <= parseTime(p.end_date_org)
    && parseTime(p.start_date_org) <= p_.period_end_date
  );

  t1.push({
    ...p,
    periods: person_periods.map(({ period }) => period),
    years: person_periods.map(({ year }) => year),
  });

  t2.push(...person_periods.map(({ period, year }, i) => ({ ...p, period, year })));

  return [t1, t2];
}, [[], []]);


console.log('Transform 1: \n', transform1);
console.log('Transform 2: \n', transform2);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.0.1/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Push the met criteria into an array and using flatMap -> expand the array list into a new array list by making a function call.

```
    let periods = [
  { start_date: "2017-01-01", end_date: "2017-12-01", period: 1 },
  { start_date: "2018-01-01", end_date: "2018-12-01", period: 2 },
  { start_date: "2019-01-01", end_date: "2019-12-01", period: 3 }
];

let people = [
  { name: "Paul", 
    start_date_org: "2017-01-01", 
    end_date_org: "2018-04-01" },
  { name: "Terence",
    start_date_org: "2018-06-01",
    end_date_org: "2019-12-01" },
  { name: "Kylian",
    start_date_org: "2017-06-01", 
    end_date_org: "2019-12-01" }
];

//let parseTime = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d")
function parseTime(dateStrYMD) {
   let ts = new Date(dateStrYMD).getTime() / 1000;
   return ts;
}

function resultSet(people, periods) {
 return people.flatMap((d, i) => {
  let peoplePeriods = [];
  periods.map((x, i) => {
    if (
      parseTime(x.start_date) >= parseTime(d.start_date_org) &&  
      parseTime(x.start_date) <= parseTime(d.end_date_org)
    ) {
      peoplePeriods.push(x.period);
    }
  });

  return peoplePeriods.flatMap(p => {
    d.period = p;
    d.year = new Date(d.start_date_org).getFullYear();
    return {
      ...d
    }
  })
 })
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(resultSet(people, periods)));
```